# When I nest a query within another query I am getting the error "SQL error 1241 operand should contain 5 column(s)"

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-clause

```
SELECT *
FROM AUTHOR
WHERE FLOOR(DATEDIFF(bDate,CURDATE())/365.25*-1) > 30 AND
    (SELECT a.*
    FROM AUTHOR a 
    WHERE (SELECT count(paperId) from AUTHOR_PAPER ap where ap.authorId = a.aEmail)) > 3
```

Both these queries work on their own, I just want to be able to find out both where clauses

Tables

```
author
(aEmail*
,fName
,lName
,bDate
,city
)

reviewer
(rEmail*
,phoneNumber
,lName
,fName
,city
)

paper
(paperId*
,title
,abstract
,submissionDate
)

author_paper
(authorId*
,paperId*
,isContact
)

paper_review
(paperId*
,reviewerId*
,score 
,reviewSubmissionDate
,reviewInvitationDate
)

* = (component of) PRIMARY KEY
```

Error im getting is :   17:05:14    SELECT * FROM AUTHOR WHERE FLOOR(DATEDIFF(bDate,CURDATE())/365.25*-1) > 30 AND  (SELECT a.*     FROM AUTHOR a      WHERE (SELECT count(*) from AUTHOR_PAPER ap where ap.authorId = aEmail)) > 3 LIMIT 0, 1000   Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 5 column(s)    0.000 sec

aEmail = authorId

Comment: This should probably be a `JOIN` as a `SELECT` inside a `SELECT` inside a `SELECT` is a bit much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want authors that are older than 30 and that produced more than 3 papers. If so, I would recommend:

```
select *
from author a
where 
    bdate <= current_date - interval 31 year
    and (select count(*) from author_paper ap where ap.authorid = a.email) > 3
```

Comment: A question though. Is it more efficient doing a Join, Group by and a Having in the end? Or no difference?

Comment: how would I return only specific values of from the table, such as I want to return only the Id of the author

Comment: @Ergis: the subquery solution should be an efficient approach. You can modify the `select` clause and enumerate the `author` columns you are interested in.

Comment: @GMB how would I setup the tables to figure out if papers could have more than one author.